# Bialetti Brikka..is 2 cup really 1 cup?

Tags: espresso, moka

My bialetti brikka claims to be a 2 cup espresso maker. However, I only see one water fill line. When I use this line, it produces one cup of espresso. 
I thought there might be a second fill line for the second cup. 
Is it implied that I would fill the water line and pour into the base twice to achieve a 2 cup espresso? Won't this throw the whole ratio of water to heat to time ?

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your [definition of "cup"](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/why-is-a-cup-of-coffee-not-6-oz/2319#2319)...

Answer (score 4):

The Bialetti two Cup stove top produces 100ml of coffee. That is in fact much more than two average espressos. A double shot pulled from an espresso machine would have between 40ml and 60ml.
Your Brikka should thus produce roughly two double shots of espresso. Well it is not actually espresso, but that's a whole different topic.
As far as I know there is only one "marker", which is actually the pressure valve. You should fill the water slightly below the valve. Then you'll get the 100ml.

Answer (score 1):

There is a marker on the inner wall of the top vessel, marked H2O. According to the manual you should measure the water in the upper vessel and pour this measured amount in the bottom one. Btw the level of water then roughly coincides with the level of the pressure valve.