# What does moka pot cups mean?

Tags: moka

I bought a moka pot days ago and have been using it almost everyday, each time i fill it with ground coffee and enough water and i drink it all by myself.

Today i noticed that on its box its written 4 cups, what does it mean?
Does it mean its for 4 people and ive been drinking too much coffee each time?

And im rather new to coffee drinking, so how much coffee does one drinks each time?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, four cups means four servings - but a serving is an espresso cup, not a mug.

In the different coffee cultures around the world, there seems to be some correlation between cup size and strength of the brew, with the amount of coffee beans per serving very roughly the same per serving and varying amounts of water used.

If you are a new coffee drinker, I would suspect that four servings in one go would give you quite a “kick”, but individual caffeine tolerance varies. As for how much you *should* drink, that’s up to you, unless you have a medical condition where your healthcare provider tells you otherwise or you are a breastfeeding mother (“infant high on caffeine” is an experience you as parent will likely not want to repeat).

Comment: Wow. This looks like synchronized diving. We wrote the same thing and sent at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Moka pots, of which the standards are more or less defined by Bialetti, produce enough coffee for indicated number of people. However, this amount may seem limited to many other cultures. Italians tend to drink as less as 30 ml of coffee as their ordinary unit. For example, in United States this is around 6 oz. (~170 ml). This is 6 times more than an Italian coffee by volume.

So, being able to drink all four cups of coffee may be relevantly normal in some other cultures. The amount of coffee you consume is better to be measured by the amount of grounds you have used. Although, even this amount may change a lot among people.

Actually, I believe everything seems normal in your habits.

Please also see these discussions as they may be relevant:

- [Bialetti Brikka..is 2 cup really 1 cup?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/bialetti-brikka-is-2-cup-really-1-cup)
- [Is it possible to overdose on coffee?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4479/is-it-possible-to-overdose-on-coffee)